# Translator in an invented language django

Tags: python, html, css, django

I am currently coding my first website, which is a translator in an invented language. You input a random phrase and it should get translated in the invented language. Here's the code for the translation:

```
class TranslatorView(View):
    template_name=  'main/translated.html'

    def post (self, request,*args, **kwargs):
        return render(request, self.template_name)
        
    def get (self, request, phrase, *args, **kwargs):
        phrase = request.POST.get('text', 'translation')
        translation = phrase
        for letter in phrase:
            if letter.lower() in "a":
                if letter.isupper():
                    translation = translation + "U"
                else:
                    translation = translation + "u"
            elif letter.lower() in "t":
                if letter.isupper():
                    translation = translation + "A"
                else:
                    translation = translation + "a"
            elif letter.lower() in "c":
                if letter.isupper():
                    translation = translation + "G"
                else:
                    translation = translation + "g"
            elif letter.lower() in "g":
                if letter.isupper():
                    translation = translation + "C"
                else:
                    translation = translation + "c"
        context = {
            'translation': translation
        }
        return render(request,'main/translator.html', context)
```

Template where you input the phrase:

```
{% extends "base.html"%}

{% block content%}
<form action="{% url 'translated' %}" method="post">{% csrf_token %}
    <div class="form-group">
        <center><h2 class = "display-3">TRANSLATE YOUR DNA CHAIN</h2></center>
        <br>
        <br>
        <textarea class="form-control" name='text' id="exampleFormControlTextarea1" rows="6"></textarea>
        <br>
        <button type='Submit' class= "btn btn-primary btn-lg btn-block">Translate</button>


    
      </div>   
</form>
{% endblock content %}
```

Template where the text should appear translated:

```
{% extends "base.html"%}

{% block content%}

<div >
    <center><h2 class = "display-4">DNA TRANSLATED SUCCESFULLY INTO</h2></center>
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>

    <center>
        <h3>
        {{ translation }}
    </h3>
    </center>
       

    
</div>   

{% endblock content%}
```

Here's the thing, when I translate the phrase and redirects me to the translated template, the text that I wrote (Example: dadada) doesn't appear.
[image]

I have no clue where the error is. If someone knows the error, please answer because I'm stuck.

Thanks

Comment: You've got your method names switched around. Rename `def get()` to `def post()` and vice versa, then it will work!

Comment: I've changed my function and now the text appears, but it is not translated. What should I do?